# Nativescript 5.0 - displaying react/angular webapp read from local path inside WebView component on Android

Tags: webview, nativescript

It is possible to display an react/angular web application on **WebView** component ?

I build angular(angular cli) and react application in prod mode. 
Next, prepared files I put inside **./assets** folder. 
After changes inside **webpack.config.js** and run 
**tns run android --bundle** than nothing is shown beside of static texts.

**home.component.tns.html**

```
 <GridLayout>
     <WebView src="~/assets/seatmap/index.html"></WebView>
 </GridLayout>
```

**home.component.tns.html**

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>t</title>
 <base href="/">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.x.css"></head>
 <body>
     <img src="favicon.ico"> // not displayed
     <img src="./favicon.ico"> // displayed
     <app-root></app-root> // nothing is displayed
     <b>This text is displayed</b>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.x.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.x.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="main.x.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Javascript files are loaded. There is no problem with path.
When I change **src** to any external web site (src="http://facebook.com") everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [NativeScript WebView loading local resources in src document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53309673/nativescript-webview-loading-local-resources-in-src-document)

It's known issue with iOS, please refer my answer there which includes possible workarounds.

Comment: Thanks Manoj, I have problem on Android, so similar solution should I apply like you suggested for iOS ?

Comment: For Android, the path has to be absolute.

Comment: After  investigation I have found reason why web application written in Angular didn`t  display on WebView component well.  Just, wrong command used for build angular application. If anyone meet similar problem, try to build angular application in following command : ng build --base-href='./' --prod.