# Load Local HTML/JavaScript/CSS Inside NativeScript App

Tags: android-webview, nativescript, wkwebview, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

With a NativeScript iOS and Android app using Angular, how do I load, inside of a WebView, a locally stored html file that has JS and CSS references? I am able to display the WebView but I get the error that the file is not found because I do not know where to point the src from my component.

Currently I have the files inside src/assets and in there is the index.html

Is there a more appropriate place to store these files within the app? Is there a better way to display this than a WebView? How do I reference this file as the source of a WebView?

I will also be needing to know how to reference a file the app downloads. Where does iOS and Android store downloaded files from within the app? How do i reference these files from my WebView?

Thank you.

Comment: Use absolute paths to load files. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53309673/nativescript-webview-loading-local-resources-in-src-document, check the example and linked Github issue.

Comment: @Manoj how do I know what the absolute path is of a bundled folder in assets or of a downloaded file? I know what an absolute path is, but I can't seem to find out what that path is. I am using an emulator...also thank you for the link. This is not a duplicate of that because the issue is not a bug - I am asking to know what the absolute path to a folder is that is bundled and also downloaded and how to put that as the src of a WebView. Thank you.

Comment: You have everything you need form the Playground example linked, it was demonstrating on loading an external image. I even double checked with [external JS files](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=2Jslpt&v=9) and it works the same way. If you are packaging your HTML / JS / Images within app, then all you have to do is to use app directory instead of temp directory.

Comment: @Manoj Thank you. It was the use of 'tns-core-modules/file-system' that allowed me to locate the proper file path. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad, you figured it out. Added same as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use absolute path while importing local JS / CSS / Image into WebView. Here is a [Playground sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=2Jslpt&v=9). Unlike the given example if you want to load files those are packed with app, simply use app directory instead with right path to file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using path like:

```
src='~/assets/player.iframe.html'
```

And in the `webpack.config.js` I just added

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: { glob: "assets/**" } },          <= Added this row
                { from: { glob: "fonts/**" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.jpg" } },
                ...
```

Comment: also, in `tsconfig.json`  there's a `"paths"` key. which describe what each `~` is mapped to. i.e in my new project it's now `"~/*: "src/*"` so now the path to such image ( w/o webpack change ) will be: `~/app/assets/...` as `~` is the root.