# Assets Folder Not Including HTML Files In NativeScript Android Build

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui

I am trying to display a local html file with JS and CSS and PNG images referenced by it. I put the files into my assets folder of a NativeScript x Angular app for Android. When I run tns run android --bundle and the app gets built - the assets folder does not include the html. Folder structure goes from assets > index.html (and index.html references the other files).

Is there a certain place or way I need to include html files so they get included in the build?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must update `CopyWebpackPlugin` in your `webpack.config.js` to include the asset folder

```
// Copy assets to out dir. Add your own globs as needed.
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
 { from: "fonts/**" },
 { from: "**/*.jpg" },
 { from: "**/*.png" },
 { from: "assets/**" }, // Add your asset folder path like this
], { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),
```

Comment: Thanks again! This was the second part to my first issue you solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53732871/load-local-html-javascript-css-inside-nativescript-app

Comment: Or in the newer version of nativescript, weback file is mostly empty, just add rules: `webpack.Utils.addCopyRule('**/*.jpeg')`