# Trouble storing and loading images locally in Nativescript on IOS

Tags: ios, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

1) Storing images locally to be displayed later via the html, most all of the docs say to store them like in ~/images/image1.png. Typescript/Nativescript says to store these by doing this:
fileSystemModule.knownFolders.currentApp(), then join the "/images/image1.png and write the file. This works great on IOS and Android in debug mode and the simulators, but it doesn't work in a Release version of IOS. IOS gives an error saying you can't access this folder. The nativescript documentation clearly says for currentApp that " iOS - this folder is read-only and contains the app and all its resources.".
Thus, if it's IOS, I do what the doc for the Filesystem/IOS module says:

```
var dirPath;
if (isIOS) {
    dirPath = fileSystemModule.knownFolders.ios.library();
    dirPath = fileSystemModule.path.join(fileSystemModule.knownFolders.ios.library().path, '/Application Support/myapp/images/image1.png');
```

I'm able to write and read files from here from TS code fine. However,
2) For displaying these in my page, for an image in my html, I have src='~./Library/Application Support/myapp/images/image1.png' and it's not able to find them. Any suggestions appreciated.
There are a lot of docs saying how to write files locally using currentApp(), but none talk about how this doesn't work in the Release version of IOS.

Comment: Which one you are trying to use, currentApp or library directory? currentApp is read only on iOS, there is no way you could write file to that directory.

Comment: I'm using the Library directory that's returned from the fileSystemModule.knownFolders.ios.library() and use the Application Support sub-directory as advised by Apple and have my own folder underneath there. I'm able to write and read json files from there from Typescript. I'm also able to write my Images there, it's just that I can't reference them from my .html files so Nativescript can find them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load Local HTML/JavaScript/CSS Inside NativeScript App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53732871/load-local-html-javascript-css-inside-nativescript-app)

Comment: Not quite. That's how to reference files included with your app which can be done with Image src="res://logo.jpg" if I included that in my app. These are files I've written to the file system. Thanks.

Comment: Found the work around. In the HTML where I need to reference the image location, I put the full file path name. Called the same function I was using to when I was writing the images to the file system and add that to the front of the image file name, like src="getAppFolderPath()+'/images/image1.png'. 
getAppFolderPath() uses the ios.library() function above. Note that you get different locations for it VS debug simulator, VS debug IOS device, and IOS Release version on IOS.