# NativeScript-vue: Unable to display local HTML in WebView

Tags: android, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm using NativeScript-vue.

I want to use WebView to display an HTML file in a local asset.

`src/components/App.vue`:

```xml
<template>
  <Frame>
    <Page>
      <GridLayout columns="*" rows="*">
        <WebView row="0" col="0" src="~/assets/index.html" />
      </GridLayout>
    </Page>
  </Frame>
</template>
```

`src/main.ts`:

```js
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue';
import App from './components/App.vue';

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$start();
```

`src/assets/index.html`:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>test</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`App_Resources/Android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="__PACKAGE__"
    android:versionCode="10000"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

        <activity
            android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|locale|uiMode"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">

            <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Now, I get the error "ERR_ACCESS_DENIED" when I run this application on Android Emulator.

[image]

This situation is the same with the actual device instead of the emulator.

Is there any possible cause?

Environment:

- npm:

  - @nativescript/core: 7.0.3
  - nativescript-socketio: 3.3.1
  - nativescript-vue: 2.8.1
- Emulator: API 30, Android 11.0, x86

Curiously, it works fine with the Android 10.0 (API 29, x86) emulator.

Comment: maybe you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63535281/10772133

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Probably my webpack settings are correct. HTML file is located in the "assets" directory, and the CopyWebpackPlugin setting in webpack is correct.  -----> ` { from: 'assets/**', noErrorOnMissing: true, globOptions: { dot: false, ...copyIgnore } }, `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that in Android 11.0 and later, file access is not allowed by default!

[Android Developers Reference: WebSettings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#setAllowFileAccess(boolean))

> The default value is true for apps targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.Q and below, and false when targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.R and above.

## resolved code

`src/components/App.vue`:

```xml
<template>
  <Frame>
    <Page>
      <GridLayout columns="*" rows="*">
        <WebView row="0" col="0" @loaded="webViewLoaded" />
      </GridLayout>
    </Page>
  </Frame>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  methods: {
    webViewLoaded(args) {
      if (args.object.android) {
        args.object.android.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); // IMPORTANT!!
        args.object.src = "~/assets/map/index.html"; // Load local HTML.
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```